# Incorrect syntax near ')' in Microsoft SQL when I'm trying to create a temporary table using WITH clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I want to combine 12 CSVs using UNION ALL into a new table. For this I used the WITH clause but it's not running because of Incorrect Syntax near End of File. This is the code I ran. I initially wanted to use CREATE TABLE but it doesn't seem to work with Microsoft SQL. Could someone let me know where I'm going wrong? Or if you know a better approach I'd love to apply that as well.

```
WITH YearlyData AS
(   SELECT * FROM ['202109-divvy-tripdata-Sept2021$']
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM ['202110-divvy-tripdata-Oct2021$']
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM ['202111-divvy-tripdata-Nov2021$']
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM ['202112-divvy-tripdata-Dec2021$']
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT * FROM ['202201-divvy-tripdata-Jan2022$']
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM ['202202-divvy-tripdata-Feb2022$']
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT * FROM ['202203-divvy-tripdata-Mar2022$']
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT * FROM ['202204-divvy-tripdata-Apr2022$']
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT * FROM ['202205-divvy-tripdata-May2022$']
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM ['202206-divvy-tripdata-June2022$']
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT * FROM ['202207-divvy-tripdata-July2022$']
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT * FROM ['202208-divvy-tripdata-Aug2022$']
)
```

Comment: *Or if you know a better approach I'd love to apply that as well* since you ask, consider properly *normalising* your data; have a single table with a *date* column, your issue just disappears completely.

Answer (score 2):

after your query you have to select YearlyData :

```
    WITH YearlyData AS
    (   SELECT * FROM ['202109-divvy-tripdata-Sept2021$']
            UNION ALL
            SELECT * FROM ['202110-divvy-tripdata-Oct2021$']
            UNION ALL
            SELECT * FROM ['202111-divvy-tripdata-Nov2021$']
            UNION ALL
            SELECT * FROM ['202112-divvy-tripdata-Dec2021$']
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT * FROM ['202201-divvy-tripdata-Jan2022$']
            UNION ALL
            SELECT * FROM ['202202-divvy-tripdata-Feb2022$']
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT * FROM ['202203-divvy-tripdata-Mar2022$']
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT * FROM ['202204-divvy-tripdata-Apr2022$']
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT * FROM ['202205-divvy-tripdata-May2022$']
            UNION ALL
            SELECT * FROM ['202206-divvy-tripdata-June2022$']
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT * FROM ['202207-divvy-tripdata-July2022$']
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT * FROM ['202208-divvy-tripdata-Aug2022$']
    )
select * from YearlyData
```